# Adding Physic Bodies to Spritekit Nodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I am making a basic game on iOS using Xcode 7 and Swift 2. I am trying to add physic bodies to nodes. On the user's character, the physic body runs fine (nothing crashes and it runs the same). However, when adding physic bodies to obstacles, the obstacle does not appear... Here is my code for the obstacle:

```
        let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(4))
        var objectTexture = SKTexture()
        var object = SKSpriteNode()
        if random == 0 {
            objectTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "coin")
            object = SKSpriteNode(texture: objectTexture)

            object.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: objectTexture.size())
            object.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Coin.rawValue
            object.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Coin.rawValue
            object.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Coin.rawValue

        }
        if random != 0 {
            objectTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "fryingPan")
            object = SKSpriteNode(texture: objectTexture)

            object.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: objectTexture.size())
            object.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Obstacle.rawValue
            object.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Obstacle.rawValue
            object.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Obstacle.rawValue

        }
        //Setting up object
```

Using this code, the object does not appear on to the screen. When I comment out the physic body lines, however, the object appears on the screen as directed. Does anyone know where I might be going wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Few tips: 1) Put some print() calls inside those if statements to see what is really executed. 2) Set zPositions correctly (objects may be hidden). 3) Make obstacles not affected by gravity which will keep them on screen and enable physics visual representation to se what is going on. Also, I can't see you are setting position of those "objects" anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

`object.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false`

I guess the gravity moves your obstacles out of the screen